# What is the formal way to say 'let me tell you about...'?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, formality

I am writing a description of a place and I need to change the sentence.

Have you ever wanted to visit a city which is surrounded by green hills and with a beautiful big lake? Well, `let me tell you about´ Tafí del Valle. It’s set...

I was wondering if there is a formal way to say 'let me tell you about'

Comment: Please explain why you feel you need to change it, and what a "formal" sentence might look like. (Obviously, since you're asking here, you can't give a "formal" sentence in this case, but perhaps you can think of another.) The reason for this comment is that formality is subjective, and there is no one right answer. You need to help the community to provide just what you need. It's also worth saying that "Have you ever wanted..." is a rhetorical device in its own right (a classic rhetorical question), and is somewhat informal. Why do you think "Let me tell you about" is not what's required?

Comment: my teacher told me it was too informal and i need to change it.

Comment: The first sentence sounds just as formal (or informal) as the second. In other words, I see nothing out of place with the second sentence within the context given. To what audience is this being delivered (even if just in theory)?

Comment: tourist brochure

Comment: Why don't you state in your question that this is for formal writing. Your teacher is right about one thing: brochures are not usually written in the first person plural. They would not contain: Let me x. Why? Because a tourist brochure is not usually signed by an author. They are written anonymously, mostly.

Answer (score 1):

A travel article may be written by an author. The author's name is printed with the article. In these cases, it is fine to address readers directly.

"Let me tell you about" is a standard way to address readers or people in an audience or conversation. It is neither formal or informal.

**A tourist brochure usually does not have an author.** Typically, tourist boards or organizations put out brochures and no one knows who wrote them. Therefore, it is not appropriate to use a narrative form of address such as "Let me tell you about".

A simple, direct statement such as the one below is an example of an appropriate writing style using a statement.

**The town of [x] sits at the foothills to the Appalachian Mountains.**

Answer (score -1):

This might depend on what exactly you said and how exactly your teacher responded, rather than any interpretation or re-phrasing…
Let’s remember first that “I am writing a description of a place and I need to change the sentence” makes sense semantically but is not correct in grammar, and the same is true of “Have you ever wanted to visit a city which is surrounded by green hills and with a beautiful big lake?”

What exactly did you say and how exactly did your teacher respond, please?
“Let me tell you about… (anything)“ is a standard story-telling form going back as far as the history of language, as should be known by every teacher of language beyond the basic.

This can most obviously be seen in the oldest known work outside Biblical scripture, *The Epic of Gilgamesh*, which in various translations does specifically include the phrase “let me tell you about…”.

That being the case, who could ever suggest, let alone prove, that any grammatically correct use of the same semantic form was in any way “wrong”?

Comment: Even for a formal tourist brochure? Hmm. Maybe if the mayor is presenting his city/region. Otherwise, nyet.

Comment: Uh… what? Very clearly, even for any kind of tourist brochure. Your "nyet" comes form what specific experience, please? Personally, I wrote dozens of tourist brochures and had I not, I would still struggle to understand why you might think they should be given special rules of grammar or semantics…

Comment: I used to write brochures for a living. Brochures are not usually signed by an author. Therefore, you would not use: Let me tell you about x because me would refer to you. If an author signs a piece, then, "Let me tell you about" x is fine. Otherwise, who is me? The anonymous brochure writer?? It's not grammar or semantics. It's point of view: "Let me tell you" establishes point of view.

Comment: Can you explain how it matters whether brochures are signed?
Could you translate “Let me tell you about x because me would refer to you” into English?
I’m sorry and when you suggest “If an author signs a piece, ‘Let me tell you about’ x is fine” you demonstrate a complete lack of any understanding of what we’re talking about, in English and prolly in your own language. 
If you must constrain yourself to Classical Greek literature, still your understanding of ”Let me tell you” raises more Questions than answers.
Would it be OK for you to read some literature, or must we rely on opinion?

Comment: "Let me tell you about [some tourist destination]" would mean the reader knows who "me" is. And brochures are not signed by the brochure writer. Ergo, you would not use "Let ***me*** tell you about"  in a tourist brochure. That could not be clearer. My language is English. And my writing mentors were all British journalists. You might want to go back to your own drawing board.

Comment: Of course the reader knows who "me" is in the relevant sense that “me” is the author. Unless his purpose is to quibble, what reader cares about the author’s actual name? Please don’t suggest that a street audience can’t understand a street artists merely by his speech and actions, but will hear him only after he’s present his calling card with name and address. 
Tamy’s teacher was equally misguided, and wholly wrong to suggest “let me tell you about” was “informal”, let alone “too informal” with or without the initial “Well…”  More…

Comment: Further… Because you don’t like a stylistic device means that you don’t like it; not that there’s any problem with it. “Let me tell you about…" remains one of - quite possibly the - oldest linguistic tricks known to man, whether you’ve noticed it before or not.
Your logic isn’t compelling; it’s simply flawed.
To put it another way, enough is enough, Lambie. If you must continue confusing poor Tamy’s education, please at least avoid extended discussions in Comments. Wouldn't you like to move this discussion to Chat?